# letのスコープについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

こういうクラスがあったとして、

```
class Book
  attr_reader :author
end
```

以下のspecを書くと、

```
let(:author){ build :author, name: '田中'}

it 'test_a' do  
  book = Book.new
  book.instance_eval do
    @author = author
  end
  expect(book.author.name).to eq '田中'
end
```

undefined method or variables 'name' for nil class 
になってしまいます。
しかし、

```
let(:author){ build :author, name: '田中'}

it 'test_a' do  
  # 一度ローカル変数に代入する。
  var_author = author
  book = Book.new
  book.instance_eval do
    @author = var_author
  end
  expect(book.author.name).to eq '田中'
end
```

にすれば解決します。
ブロックの中身ではletの値は取れずに、ブロックの外ではletの中身を取れます。
しかし、ブロックの中身も外もスコープの違いはないはずです。
letとはそもそもどういう働きなのでしょうか？？なぜブロックの中身からletで定義した変数?を参照する事ができないのでしょうか。

※注意 Bookクラスは直面している問題をわかりやすくするためのモデルで、実際にはBookクラスでテストをしているわけではありません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一言で言うと、「instance_evalの仕様が特殊だから」ということになります。
以下は詳細です。

[instance method BasicObject#instance_eval (Ruby 2.2.0)](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/BasicObject/i/instance_eval.html)

> ただし、ローカル変数だけは、文字列 expr の評価では instance_eval の外側のスコープと、ブロックの評価ではそのブロックの外側のスコープと、共有します。

上の説明にあるように、instance_evalを使った場合、ローカル変数はスコープが共有されますが、メソッドは共有されません。
そしてRSpecのletは変数のように見えますが、実際にはメソッドです。

```
defined? author # => method
```

また、

```
book.instance_eval do
  @author = author
end
```

で代入している`author`はRSpecではなく、Bookクラスのゲッターです。
つまり以下のコードと同じ意味です。

```
book.instance_eval do
  @author = self.author
end
```

というわけで結局、instance_evalの中ではletで定義した`author`を参照できていないことになります。

一方、質問の後半にある`var_author`はローカル変数なのでinstance_evalの中でも参照できます。
よって、instance_evalの中で値をセットできるわけです。

ちなみに、 instance_eval でなければブロック内でもletの値を参照することは可能です。

```
let(:x) { 1 }
example do
  y = [].tap do |a|
    a << x
  end
  expect(y).to [1]
end
```